# django, python - master -> detail

Tags: python, django

i get this error: Page not found (404) /polls/1/ when i press link from master - detail page in djangoproject tutorial (i changed directory from poll to naslovnica):

views.py:

```
def app_index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all()[:5]
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
    return render(request, 'naslovnica/index.html', context)

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except naslovnica.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'naslovnica/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
```

this is urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    url(r'^$', 'naslovnica.views.app_index'),
    url(r'^naslovnica$', 'naslovnica.views.index'),
    url(r'^naslovnica/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'naslovnica.views.detail'),
    url(r'^naslovnica/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'naslovnica.views.results'),
    url(r'^naslovnica/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'naslovnica.views.vote'),


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Can someone explain me in easy language why django is looking for "poll" directory? what is mechanism of master/detail page in django (1.6)?

edit: contest of index.html (this page show corectly)

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

detail.html:

```
{{poll}}
```

Comment: what are the contents of your index.html and detail.html files?

Comment: Okay... next up... where's your index function (you show app_index but not index) and if there's a different html file for that, please include that.  Note that I'm not seeing any "a href" links here; I was expecting you had missed renaming one in one of the templates.

Comment: here is index in views.py:
def index(request):
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 version = django.get_version()
 html = "<html><body>ovo je index od naslovnice</body></html>"
 return HttpResponse(html)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found what was wrong. Here in index.html code:

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/poll/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

line

```
<li><a href="/poll/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

should be:

```
<li><a href="/naslovnica/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

Comment: if someone can help me edit this answer to show code in right way

Comment: You can wrap your code with 3 backticks (`) at the beginning and the end to format it, or 4 spaces of indent at the beginning of each line (before actual indenting your code)